# VBA or FORMULA to update file path name with most recent working date

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, filepath

I am producing a file everyday with updated market data (the layout is identical each day, just different numbers in the tables). I have a couple of columns on each worksheet that take data from a separate file. This file has a date as part of its name.

One formula is:

`=K10-'O:\Daily Vols\PDFsourcefiles\[Daily PDF 2018.05.18..xlsm]POWERPDF'!$K$10`

This equation gives me the data in K10 today minus the data in K10 from yesterday's document.
I would like to find a way to automatically update this file path each day with the previous date on which I ran the file (NOT just date-1 as weekends can't be included!)
I am currently using 'find and replace' function but this is very time consuming and prone to human error if I forget one or two cells.

I do have today's date in cell A1 of the 'Comments' worksheet if this would be useful to use.

I hope someone out there with more experience of excel will be able to help with this - many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable in VBA. I think the Workbook_Open event would be best. The link will be made when you open the file. Assuming you don't know how to get to the VBA editor press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and double-click "ThisWorkbook". Then type the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("[YourWorksheetName]").Cells([RowNum],[ColNum]) = "=K10-'O:\Daily Vols\PDFsourcefiles\[Daily PDF " & Format(Date - 1, "yyyy.mm.dd") & "..xlsm]POWERPDF'!$K$10"
End Sub
```

Where [YourWorksheetName] is the name of the worksheet of today's file (maybe POWERPDF?), [RowNum] and [ColNum] are the row/column that you want this formula. So if this formula goes into B1 then it would be .Cells(1, 2) because B is the second column.

Hopefully that works better.

Comment: Thank you. That doesn't seem to work when I add it as a formula - did you mean a VBA instead?

Comment: No, I meant formula. That's odd that it's not working. What was the error?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I replied to this last week - #REF! was the error

Comment: Oops. Looks like I got a small case of "foot-in-mouth" syndrome. I could have sworn that this was doable with a function but it looks like VBA will be necessary. I'll edit my answer.